# Connect SAS to mongodb without using ODBC

Tags: mongodb, sas, odbc

One of ours statistician is stuck trying to read data from mongoDB using SAS.

In my experience connecting mongo to other languages always require a native driver, but in this case I've found that is only possible using ODBC.

I've tried to find a better way to connect this two software but the only idea that came to my mind is to expose mongo via webservice.

Any of you have a better solution to connect SAS to mongodb?

Comment: Is this 'better way' needed because you do not have SAS/Access to ODBC licensed ?

Comment: Better way in the sense that I will not need to install and configure ODBC on every system where SAS is used but everything is contained together (data access and analysis code)

Comment: Sounds like you answered your own question :)  Complex queries can be directed to the webservice via `Proc HTTP` and the result set captured as XML or JSON file download. There are a variety of SAS ways to parse the downloaded file into a SAS data set.

Comment: @Richard Why would you though?  It's a horrible solution.  Better solution is to configure (or automate the configuration of) ODBC .

Comment: I'd recommend finding a low-friction way of getting those ODBC connections setup on the systems where it will run.  Some of the other StackExchange sites should be able to assist in automating ODBC setups.  Not sure if SO is the right place to answer that specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tries we found that using webservice is the most convenient way to solve mongodb access in ours case.

Some statistician required to load data on laptop from outside the corporate network so we decided to extend our web service to expose some more informations and access it in SAS like this https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2016/12/02/json-libname-engine-sas/

Thanks all for the clarification regarding ODBC, to me was a real surprise that is still the preferred way to load data in enterprise environments.